# How to query an array in array of dictionaries in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a following mongoDB document structure -

```
db.menus.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cf25412326c3f4f26df039b"),
        "restaurantId" : "301728",
        "items" : [
                {
                    "itemId" : "CEBM4H41JR",
                    "name" : "Crun Chicken",
                    "imageUrl" : "",
                    "price" : 572,
                    "attributes" : [
                            "Tasty",
                            "Spicy"
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "itemId" : "53Q0XS3HPR",
                    "name" : "Devils Chicken",
                    "imageUrl" : "",
                    "price" : 595,
                    "attributes" : [
                            "Gravy",
                            "Salty"
                    ]
            }
        ]
}
```

I am trying to write a query to get all the menus based on the "attributes" field under "items" in the document.

I have done the following to get the menus if "name" of "items" is given and I am getting a result -

```
db.menus.find({ 'items' : {$elemMatch : {'name' : {$regex : "Chicken Thali", $options: 'i' }}}}).pretty()
```

I have tried this for getting the result for attributes but this is not working -

```
db.menus.find({'items' : {$elemMatch : {'attributes' : {$all : [{$regex : "Tasty", $options: 'i' }]}}}})
```

How do I get the list and I also want to write this query for mongoRepository in a spring boot application?

Further, based on the restaurantId's obtained, I have to query restaurant collection in order to find all the restaurants in restaurants collection having the following structure -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf2540e326c3f4f26de93dd"),
    "restaurantId" : "301728",
    "name" : "Desire Foods",
    "imageUrl" : "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/8/301728/d690ccb500d746530f56e1d637949da2_featured_v2.jpg",
    "latitude" : 28.4900591,
    "longitude" : 77.3066401,
    "attributes" : [
            "Chinese",
            " Fast Food",
            " Bakery"
    ],
    "opensAt" : "09:30",
    "closesAt" : "22:30"
}
```

Is the whole operation possible in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify your query to use $in instead of $all.
To achieve your intended result, you can try:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "items": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "attributes": {
            "$in": [
              "Tasty"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "restaurant",
      "localField": "restaurantId",
      "foreignField": "restaurantId",
      "as": "restaurants"
    }
  },
  {
      "$unwind": "restaurants"
  },
  {
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$restaurants" }
  }
])
```

Use $match at appropriate stages as needed to limit the documents pulled in memory